# Proof Verification of a statement regarding dimension of the sum of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the statement I am trying to prove.

> Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional. Prove that if $U_1,\ldots,U_m$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $V = U_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus U_M$ then $\operatorname{dim} V = \operatorname{dim} U_1 + \cdots + \operatorname{dim} U_m$.

This is from Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler. He has a wonderful proof in the solutions manual but it is not a very obvious one (outside of retrospect). I recognize there are many other ways to prove this statement but here is my attempt.

Define a sequence of $V_j$ such that $V_1 = U_1$ and $V_j = V_{j-1}\oplus U_j$. It is clear that $V = V_m = V_{m-1}\oplus U_m$.

Using the fact that $\operatorname{dim}(W_1 \oplus W_2) = \operatorname{dim}(W_1) + \operatorname{dim}(W_2)$ we can write that

$$\begin{align} \operatorname{dim}(V) &= \operatorname{dim}(V_m) \\ &=\operatorname{dim}(V_{m-1} \oplus U_m)\\&=  \operatorname{dim}(V_{m-1}) + \operatorname{dim}(U_m) \\&=\operatorname{dim}(V_{m-2}\oplus U_{m-1}) + \operatorname{dim}(U_m) \\ &= \operatorname{dim}(V_{m-2}) + \operatorname{dim}(U_{m-1}) + \operatorname{dim}(U_m)
\\&\,\,\vdots \\ &= \operatorname{dim} (U_1) + \cdots + \operatorname{dim} (U_m)\end{align}$$

Is this a valid outline of a proof? It seems much more natural than anything else but it also feels like cheating.

Comment: Just chose a basis for each $U_i$ putting them together you get a basis for the whole space.

Comment: Looks fine, @user...but you need there some inductive argument, I think.

Comment: The ellipsis is most properly replaced with an appeal to mathematical induction.